# Magento to NodeJS via REST APIs using OAuth

Tags: node.js, magento, oauth, restful-authentication

I'm trying to call one of Magento REST APIs (say products api) from a NodeJS application using a regular HTTP Request. I know that Magento APIs requires OAuth to authenticate the user/application, and this is where I'm a bit lost.

With Magento or any OAuth application, the end-user who is using the app has to click "Authorize" in order for that application to receive the token, and then the application will be able to communicate directly with Mangento APIs.

In my case, we are talking about 2 servers, Magento and NodeJS, that will talk to each other. So There is no user involve to sort of "Click" the authorize button and validate the auth request.

The point of what I'm trying to achieve is grab product data from Magento, store it in a DB, then make some changes, after that make it accessible via NodeJS REST APIs. (That is a hard requirement and I can't change it).

My question is, Do we have to write custom Magento REST APIs that doesn't require OAuth, or maybe require the regular basic HTTP Authentication (username/password). Or there is a way to use OAuth and authenticate my Node application directly?

I hope my question is clear, if not please let me know and I will try to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling with a similar situation, I decided to use Magento's SOAP API.  All you have to do as far as authentication goes is to set up an API user in the Magento backend and then use the username/password in your API calls (I think, it's been awhile).  Not sure if this fits your use case but it saved me a lot of OAuth headache.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your response. We sticked with the OAuth for that project, it was a pain. I wish we thought about that before! Thanks again!